# Javascript - Execute function every x seconds, but only execute function 3 times

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been doing some research into this, and I came up with nothing.  Basically, I am trying to write a data collection program that calls a function 3 times, waiting 10 seconds in between each call.  But, all I can find is "How to call a function every x seconds for y seconds", and it doesn't solve my problem completely, since it may take more than y seconds to complete all three calls.  I know I will have to use the setInterval and clearIntervals, but I don't know how I would go about formatting my loops.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use setInterval and keep a counter on each run then, clear the interval when the count gets large enough.

```
(function() {
  var c = 0;
  var timeout = setInterval(function() {
    //do thing
    c++;
    if (c > 2) {
      clearInterval(timeout);
    }
  }, 10000);
})();
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bNVMQy

Comment: High five fellow McNally!

Answer (score 9):

Use `setTimeout`:

```
function callNTimes(n, time, fn) {
  function callFn() {
    if (--n < 0) return;
    fn();
    setTimeout(callFn, time);
  }
  setTimeout(callFn, time);
}
```

Then you can use that function to set up your counted iteration:

```
callNTimes(3, 10000, function() { /* whatever */ });
```

Comment: would there be a max number of times where this would cause a stack issue?

Comment: @Ridderhoff no, because one function call will finish completely long before the next even starts. At any given instant, there will be at most one call to the function taking place. (Mostly it will be zero calls, of course, since most of the time it's just waiting for time to pass.)'